# How to replace <span style="text-decoration: underline;"> </span> with <u></u> tag for a dynamic string in angular 6

Tags: html, angular

I have a input box where user enters string and does some string formatting like font name, bold,italic,underline, font size etc. for selected text. When user underlines any word or sentence then that word/sentence source code is like `<span style="text-decoration: underline;"></span>`
If user changes font size or font name then `<span style="font-family"...>` or `<span style="font-size"...`
these tags are attached.

In this i have to replace `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">` tag and its corresponding `</span>` with `<u>`and `</u>`. How to do that. Because replacing `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">` tag is easy. I can find it and replace it. But replacing its `</span>` tag is difficult, if there are more than 1 `</span>` tags. Because I need to find out which `</span>` tag need to be replaced from multiple `</span>` tags.

How can I do this in angular 6. Thank you.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, you can do this kind of replace using regular expression:

```js
var x = '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Test</span>'

function replace_span_to_u(input) {
  return input.replace(/\<span style\=\"text-decoration\: underline\;\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/g,             function(matched, index) {
          return '<u>' + index + '</u>';
        })
  }

replace_span_to_u(x)
```